# Nodes in Neo4j with same property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I have a database that stores multiple nodes representing sensors. 
Each node sensor will relate to a node date. 
So I have multiple date nodes that will have the same property value, in other words, the same date. But at the time of consulting in Cypher of an existing date like `MATCH (n:Data) WHERE n.data = '1998-01-01' RETURN n` shows that there are no rows. Can someby help me? The only property field of date nodes is "data".

Comment: I think you'll have to show us a bit more about your date nodes. Can you add the result of this query to your description? `MATCH (n:Date) RETURN n LIMIT 3`

Comment: @InverseFalcon

n
data 1998-01-01
data 1998-01-01
data 1998-01-01

Comment: Looks like you probably had a misspelling on the property, using 'data' instead of 'date'. You should be able to confirm this with `MATCH (n:Date) WHERE n.data = '1998-01-01' RETURN n`.

Comment: @InverseFalcon the label is Data and the property is data, I typed the wrong in the description

Comment: Got it. Can you update your description so it's using the correct labels and properties? Are you still not getting any nodes returned from your queries?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Updated. When I consult with `MATCH (n:Data) WHERE n.data = '1998-01-01' RETURN n` shows "no rows", but when I consult with `MATCH (n:Data) RETURN n LIMIT 3` it returns the existing nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128978/discussion-between-jessica-marinho-and-inversefalcon).

Comment: Could it be that you have leading or trailing whitespace in your property values? That would not show up in the browser's output.

Try `MATCH (d:Data) WITH d.data AS dbVal, '1998-01-01' AS inVal RETURN dbVal = inVal, ltrim(dbVal) = inVal, rtrim(dbVal) = inVal`

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was in the files that I used to import. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment but i cant yet. You should consider changing your db and have nodes representing the dates, and then the sensors nodes would have a relationship with the date nodes. This way you wont have repeated data.

This would be the schema:

`(s:sensor)-[:measured_in]->(d:Date {date:"1998-01-01"})`

And this would be the query:

`MATCH (d:date)<-[:measured_in]-(s:sensor) WHERE d.date="1998-01-01" return s`

Comment: But my database is just like this :/